# How does one go about choosing a Radar Cross Section for a human when modelling a Pulse micro-Doppler microwave radar?

Tags: radar, doppler, pulse

So as part of a personal project I'm in the process of simulating and making a fall detector using a 2.7GHz microwave sensor with a range of 8m. I've been using MATLAB's example code to simulate each part of the radar as well as a target and a distance returned which can be found here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ug/designing-a-basic-monostatic-pulse-radar.html#d123e23746

As well as a radar based on the BISS0001 Chip with data sheet: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/010/133/original/BISS0001.pdf

This seems to work quite well but one thing I'm not entirely sure on is the design specifications and how I can translate them to my radar. In MATLAB's example they have a max unambiguous range of 5000m, a resolution range of 50m and a radar cross section of 1m^2.

Given I'm not expecting more than 1 target together I figure I don't really need to worry too much about maximum range and resolution range but regardless, since the range of my radar is 8m I've put the max range as 8m and as for the range resolution I've gone for 2m.

I'm not entirely sure that those are correct but given that I'll never have more than 1 target I think it might be OK but please let me know if not.
The main thing is the Radar Cross Section as it's made up of a lot of properties I'm not definite on. Looking online at published data it seems 1m^2 is standard but does this not depend on the strength of my radar instead of just the target itself?

Answer (score 1):

As the radar cross-section (RCS) is a property of the scattering target you don't really get to choose it.  1 m<sup>2</sup> (0 dBsm) is a typical reference RCS for stating radar system performance.

A typical value for a human in S-Band is somewhere between -5 and 0 dBsm (0.3 - 1.0 m<sup>2</sup>) based on figures in [Computer Models of the Human Body Signature for Sensing Through the Wall Radar Applications](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/ADA473937).  From the description of your project it sounds like there might be some other good information in the document.

I've reproduced figure 7 below.

[image: RCS of the human body (fat man model) at 0° azimuth (front view) and 0° elevation in free-space, using a 2 mm resolution FDTD grid.]